# Есть ли нарушение лексической нормы в данном предложении?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, лексическая-сочетаемость

**Люди разделяют в своем творчестве самые сокровенные переживания с растением, а оно, дерево, становится чутким слушателем.**

Comment: Текст о том, что издавна в народном сознании особо воспринималось отдельно стоящее дерево.

Comment: mariia Уточните пожалуйста, вы хотите сказать, что авторы произведений делятся с деревом своими переживаниями в процессе творчества или герои призведений (песен, например) делятся с деревом своими переживаниями?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, окончательное редактирование должно учитывать контекст, но я бы так изменила структуру предложения:

**В своем творчестве (в процессе творчества) //люди делятся  с деревом самыми сокровенными переживаниями, а оно становится их чутким слушателем.**

Предполагается, что дерево может слушать человека и испытывать такие же  чувства, но при этом дерево разделяет чувства человека, а не наоборот. Поэтому **люди делятся чувствами, а дерево разделяется с ними эти чувства**.

1) Изменен порядок слов в первом предложении, так что ***в своем творчестве*** является детерминантом и относится ко всему предложению.

2) Пару ***растение – дерево*** лучше убрать, тогда не придется обособлять приложение. А это лишняя конструкция и по семантике, и по выразительности текста.

Answer (score 1):

1. Слово "**разделяют**" (переживания, чувства) вместо "**делятся** (ими, сообщая о них)" обычно имеет смысл "*имеют такие же* или сходные" *переживания*. Это ближе к утверждению, что дерево чувствует то же, что и человек.
2. Порядок слов не совсем удачный, спонтанный. Он наводит на мысль, что *все* люди занимаются творчеством (это не так) и что растение - это *всегда* дерево.

Пример перестроенного предложения:

> В процессе творчества люди делятся самыми сокровенными переживаниями с деревом - для
>   них растение становится чутким слушателем.

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу нарушений лексической нормы как таковой, но есть два замечания.

1. Как уже говорилось (Alex_ander), есть неудачное использование слова "разделять". "Делить", конечно, тут точнее. Но это в том случае, если "дерево" не выступает в качестве одушевленного, наделенного эмоциями объекта.
2. Слово "творчество" выбивается из стиля. Искусствовед, допустим, может назвать "народное творчество" творчеством, но сам "творец" таковым его не воспринимает. Но не могу найти замену, может выбросить его совсем? Ну ведь и так ясно, о чем речь, нет? Смысла назвать дерево "растением" тоже большого не вижу.

В отношении порядка слов претензий не имею, но с учетом вышесказанного, я бы упростил до так:

*Люди делятся с деревом своими сокровенными переживаниями, а оно, дерево, становится чутким слушателем.*

Это не идеал, можно ещё улучшать, но это ужу как автор пожелает.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно бы понять, люди делятся с деревом в процессе творческого созидания или в созданных ими произведениях (стихах и песнях). Скорее второе. То есть речь идет не о процессе творчества, а о том, что создано в результате этой деятельности. А для того, чтобы избежать двусмысленности, лучше сказать "в произведениях".

Допустим, такой вариант.

**В произведениях народного творчества люди делятся с деревом самыми сокровенными переживаниями, а оно становится их чутким слушателем.**

Comment: Тогда было бы так: в произведениях народного творчества герои делятся с деревом... А здесь речь идет о творчестве конкретных авторов, а не о народном творчестве.

Comment: @Jasmin Я попросил автора вопроса внести ясность.